# C# Windows Search: how to detect that a location is in search index without interop library?

Tags: c#, com, windows-search

We use Windows Search in our application and need a way to detect is folder indexed.
I know 2 ways to do it:
1. Using `Microsoft.Search.Interop.dll` library.
2. Using [Windows Search Sample Code](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/windowssearch) (maybe a bit changed) as an .exe file called from C# application.

These two solutions need using an external file (`.dll` or `.exe`) but I need a simpler solution because it will be simple new optional SEARCH feature to a WebDAV server generated by wizard for our clients. Besides `Microsoft.Search.Interop.dll` is for .NET 2.0 and there can be a problem using it from IIS under .NET 4.0 pool (depending on pool settings).

Is there any way to use `ISearchCrawlScopeManager` interface without linking to any `.dll` (just to COM) like it was made in `Crawl Scope Command Line` C++ example?

**UPDATE1:** Looks like `ISearchCrawlScopeManager` interface is located in `Search Interface Type Library`. It isn't done yet, but I'm close. Thanks to Hans Passant.

Comment: A COM interop library is not tied to any particular .NET version.  There's little to them, they just contain declarations, no code.  So little that you don't even have to deploy it anymore when you use .NET 4, the Embed Interop Types feature removes the need.  Automatically turned on in VS2010 and later when you add the reference.

Comment: I looked through the Interop library code by Reflector. It is sophisticated and has too many usages of other declarated types. I'll read about Embed Interop Types. Thank you.